# Error: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am using SSH to try to push a new repo to GitHub.

The steps I took:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:******/**********
git push -u origin master
```

At this point, I got:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.113)' can't be established.
```

and

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Then I created an SSH key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "*****@******.com"
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I copied and added the key to my GitHub account.

Then when I ran:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/********/.ssh/id_rsa': 
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There should be no access right restrictions, as this is my repo.  I'm typing the password as I created it for the key.

What's happening?

Comment: try `ssh -vvv git@github.com verify`

Comment: Double check origin is correct. You can view those settings by doing         
          git remote -v

Answer (score 0):

Are you owner of the GitHub repo? If not, that could be a reason. Ask project owner or org admin to add you to the list of collaborators.